# Monitoring a remote process

Tags: c#, process

I have a method that stops a service(s) but I also need to delete the logs.  Usually this is not a problem but the process can take a little bit of time before closing.  Again, although the service appears stopped, the process does take additional time to close properly.  Since the process is still running, I cannot delete the logs so I need to find a way to monitor the .exe to know when its safe to delete the logs.

so far my best option is a do while loop, unfortunately the first iteration of the delete statement throws an exception and stops the program.

```
do
{
// delete logs
}
while (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(processName, machineName).Length > 0);
```

Im sure there is a simple solution but my lack of experience is the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best answer either, but you could invert the loop to:

```
while (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(processName, machineName).Length > 0)
{
    // delete log files.
}
```

I would suppose this would evalutate the condition of the loop before executing the contents. But according to your statements, this will not execute the code until the process has exited.

A hackish way around this is to perform a loop, and break out manually once the conditions:

```
bool CloseProcessOperation = true; // Control variable incase you want to abort the loop
while (CloseProcessOperation)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(processName, machineName).Length > 0) { break; }  
    // break if no logs exist
    // break for some other condition
    // etc

    // delete logs
}
```

Comment: Correct, the problem with this is that the Length is 1 while the process is running so the 'delete log' code would not be executed unless this was called after the processes stopped.  It would not wait for the process to end, which is what I need.

Comment: Couldn't you just change the '<' to a '>'? This has the same logic as the example you posted except this checks the exit condition before executing the loop contents.

Comment: Thanks greg, I really appreciate it.